# Softlayer rest call giving multiple entries for invoice in json response when object filter is applied to relational properties

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using below rest call, I am seeing multiple records for a single invoice.
I realized it repeated for as many items are there in that invoice.

Rest request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/<Account-ID>/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"items":{"billingItem":{"hourlyFlag":{"operation":"0"}}}}}
```

to be replaced by actual account number in Softlayer.

Actual result should be, it should show one single record for one invoice.

Answer (score 0):

The invoice will be displayed the times that "**hourlyFlag=0**" exists in the items from it. So it means if the invoice is displayed three times, there exists three items inside the invoice which has that flag (**hourlyFlag=0**)

You can verify that, using an objectMask like this:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"items":{"billingItem":{"hourlyFlag":{"operation":"0"}}}}}&objectMask=mask[id,items[billingItem[id,hourlyFlag]]]

Method: Get
```

**Using Result Limits:**

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"items":{"billingItem":{"hourlyFlag":{"operation":"0"}}}}}&objectMask=mask[id,items[billingItem[id,hourlyFlag]]]&resultLimit=0,50

Method: Get
```

Comment: Hi Ruber, thanks for the reply,however my requirement is to get only the items from the invoices where hourly flag is true. But doing above gives me multiple entries of Invoices in response , suppose an invoice is having 3 items as hourly flag as true, i see 3 results in response, instaed i would like to see only single result with 3 items under that invoice object.

Comment: and after running you rest URL in postman i am getting below error.                             "error": "Allowed memory size of 402653184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92 bytes)",  will be really thankful if you could please help me out with it.

Comment: That exception means that there are a lot of data to retrieve, here more info about it: 
[How to Solve: Error fetching http headers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/how-solve-error-fetching-http-headers), I updated my answer providing a request using resultLimits

Comment: For your requirement, if you would like to get that information as you describe, it's necessary to use a programming language, to see languages supported by SoftLayer: see [SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately, using Rest, it's necessary to make two request to the below methods:
[SoftLayer_Account::getInvoices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices) and
[SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/getItems), so I recommend to use a programming language. I can help you with any supported language by SoftLayer, if you would like to use one of them