# Getting "error": "Internal Error" on Postman and getting error Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

While hitting below Softlayer rest url from Postman getting error:

> "Internal Error"

And when hitting the same rest url from java code using spring restTemplate getting error as

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of
>   START_OBJECT token.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/<Account-ID>/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["03/25/2017 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value": ["04/24/2017 23:59:59"]}]},"typeCode":{"operation":"RECURRING"}}}&objectMask=mask[id,items[id,recurringFee,recurringTaxAmount,oneTimeFee,oneTimeTaxAmount,description,hostName,domainName,hourlyRecurringFee,laborFee,laborTaxAmount,setupFee,setupTaxAmount,category[name],location[longName],billingItem[id,activeFlag,hourlyFlag,allowCancellationFlag,cancellationDate,orderItem[id,order[id,userRecord[username]]]]]]
```

Comment: but above rest url if i remove this orderItem[id,order[id,userRecord[username]]]  much from last the url workes perfectly in both the places....really frustrating..

Answer (score 0):

The REST URL you posted is working when the invoices don't have a lot of items.  You are getting ***"Internal Error"*** because internally some invoices are returning the error ***"Allowed memory size of 402653184 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 131072 bytes)"***, this when is added

```
orderItem[id,order[id,userRecord[username]]]
```

I got the same error with just one invoice, on my case the invoice have more than 1500 items, this is a lot of items.

Your mask is very big in depth and there are a lot of data to retrieve, for that reason Ruber recommends here [Softlayer rest call giving multiple entries for invoice in json response when object filter is applied to relational properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640651/softlayer-rest-call-giving-multiple-entries-for-invoice-in-json-response-when-ob) use some programming language in order to retrieve all data you required:

Basically you need to do the following:

**Step 1:** 
Get all invoices by using [SoftLayer_Account::getInvoices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices), based on you requirements it should be something like this:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["03/25/2017 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value": ["04/24/2017 23:59:59"]}]},"typeCode":{"operation":"RECURRING"}}}&objectMask=mask[id,createDate]
```

This will return the ID of all invoices, you will need this in the following step

**Step 2:** 
For each retrieved invoice use the method [SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/getItems), use resultLimits and your mask as following.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/[invoiceId]/getItems?resultLimit=100,0&objectMask=mask[id,recurringFee,recurringTaxAmount,oneTimeFee,oneTimeTaxAmount,description,hostName,domainName,hourlyRecurringFee,laborFee,laborTaxAmount,setupFee,setupTaxAmount,category[name],location[longName],billingItem[id,activeFlag,hourlyFlag,allowCancellationFlag,cancellationDate,orderItem[id,order[id,userRecord[id,username]]]]]
```

Change **[invoiceId]** by each ID you retrieved in the step 1.

On this case you need to use loops, the first loop to call [SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/getItems) for each invoice and the second loop to retrieve items 100 by 100.(Instead of 100  you can set another value in resultLimit parameter)

If you set **resultLimit=100,1** it will return all items between 101 to 200. I suggest to review https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-result-limits-softlayer-api

I recommend to use languajes like [Python](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python), [Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java), [Go](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go), [Ruby](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-ruby), etc. You can see the list here https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/softlayer-api-overview.

**Note:** Unfortunately the object-filters feature is not supported by SoftLayer Java API.

I hope this help you.

Regards,